# I want to reduce number of files after electron has packaged my app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I see there are 10,000 files after electron has packaged my app. I see most of them are from node_modules directory. I have restructured package.json such that I have only the needed packages under node_modules.

My idea is, using asar option of electron-packager to package only node_modules but I don't know to do this or if anyone has better approach to reduce number of files in electron, please go ahead. Thank you

Here is the script inside package.json I tried using ordering but that works only for files, there are commands/sub function to unpackage specific directory or files but I want it to work the other way.

```
"builderForWindows": "electron-packager --out winx64 --overwrite --platform win32 --appname xyx . --executable-name xyz --asar//what sub property to use here",
```

Comment: what does your `package.json` file look like? Also look at the `--prune` directive